# Intersection of linear extensions

Tags: graph-theory

This is a question from my graph theory course. I have never felt comfortable finding linear extensions nor the intersection of linear extensions, so I was hoping to have someone look over my solution and thought process.

Sketch the diagram of P, the strict partial order with this set of linear extensions: {(a, b, c, d),(a, b, d, c),(b, a, c, d),(b, a, d, c)}.

My Solution: I am assuming that these 4 are the only linear extensions of the strict partial order. We can see that a is always greater than c and d, but a and b are equal. It can also be seen that b is greater than c and d. Finally, c and d appear to be equal. Therefore, I believe the strict partial order must be the following:
[image]

Comment: Rereading your post, my revised guess is you want someone to validate your solution to a different problem:  Given a set of total orders on the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$, find the partial order which has these (and only these) "linear" extensions.

Comment: In this course, we have been asked to take a graph of a strict partial order and use an algorithm to decompose it down into all possible linear extensions. We then can try to find a combination of those linear extensions that the intersection of gives back the original graph of the strict partial order. In this case, I believer we are doing the opposite: we are given the list of all linear extensions and are being asked to recreate the graph of the strict partial order using them.

Comment: @Barmacide1: If your linear extensions list elements in descending order, then I agree with your reconstruction of $P$. (I’d have interpreted them the other way round, but you know what conventions you’ve been using.)